# How can I implement Equalizer in my iPhone application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, avaudioplayer, equalizer

I am Developing the iPad app which has  Equalizer functionality,which  means sound play on three properties( Low, High, Medium). I googled it and found this link: [iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html)

Its basically mixes the sound but I want to apply equalizer effects on my sound.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Audio Unit Component Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) documentation. Specifically:

`kAudioUnitType_Effect            = 'aufx'`,

and Effect Audio Unit Subtypes:

```
enum {
   kAudioUnitSubType_PeakLimiter          = 'lmtr',
   kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor    = 'dcmp',
   kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2              = 'rvb2',
   kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter        = 'lpas',
   kAudioUnitSubType_HighPassFilter       = 'hpas',
   kAudioUnitSubType_BandPassFilter       = 'bpas',
   kAudioUnitSubType_HighShelfFilter      = 'hshf',
   kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter       = 'lshf',
   kAudioUnitSubType_ParametricEQ         = 'pmeq',
   kAudioUnitSubType_Delay                = 'dely',
   kAudioUnitSubType_Distortion           = 'dist',
   kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ             = 'ipeq',
   kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ              = 'nbeq'
};
```