# can I use AVAudioPlayer to make an equalizer player?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audiounit, equalizer

I want to make an equalizer for music player,which can do some EQ setting like bass and treble,and I want to change the music effect by setting the frequency.
*250Hz*, *1000Hz*, *16000Hz*.

```
(void)setEQ:(@"250Hz");
(void)setEQ:(@"1000Hz z");
(void)setEQ:(@"16000Hz");
```

But I can not find any API of AVAudioPlayer to set frequency.Can anyone help me? I will be very grateful.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164416/how-can-i-implement-equalizer-in-my-iphone-application?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

i think AVAudioplayer is not support for Equalizer Effect, for this you need to apply bands for all audio units but by using   STKAudioPlayer u can achieve it easily. refer following link it will help you.

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit